# Requirejs and Grunt: mainConfigFile vs grunt task options

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

I find there to be a lot of confusion/lack a specific way of handling building with require in grunt.  I'm just confused what configuration should go directly in Grunt task options:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: './js',
                mainConfigFile: 'config.js',
                optimize: 'none',
                include: ['./main'],
                out: 'optimized.js'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And then in config file:

```
({
    appDir: './',
    baseUrl: './js',
    dir: './dist',
    optimize: 'none',
    optimizeCss: 'standard',
    removeCombined: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: './js/jQuery/jquery',
    }
})
```

Obviosuly there seems to be some redundancy but that is mostly what I've found.  Can someone explain why or if I'm mistaken?  Can I place all config in one or the other?  I'm only planning on working off of the optimized single file with almond.

Also do I only state the initial single point of entry to build the dependency chain from ie my main.js file and any require calls in there or can I state a wildcard list of files that calls modules:

```
include: ['./variousFiles/*.js']
```

Any and all clarifications of how to best utilize require with Grunt will be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use RequireJS' `r.js` optimizer there are two configurations to speak of:

1. The **runtime** configuration which is what is described in the [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html). This is where you tell RequireJS where to find modules *at runtime.*
2. The **build** configuration, which is what is described with [`r.js`' documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). This tells `r.js` how to build bundles from your modules.

The `mainConfigFile` option is for the build configuration, it tells `r.js` where to find the *runtime* configuration you plan to use when you run the bundles it will create. This is to prevent having to duplicate `shim` and `paths` options from the runtime configuration to the build configuration.

In your description, it looks like you are making `mainConfigFile` point to a build configuration. This is useless.

Comment: Thanks Louis  That's what I began to gather as I read more.  I'm still just a little confused as to if I even need a **runtime** config if I'm only using require in a grunt build?  If that's true is it best practice to to write all my **build** config in my require task options(shim, paths etc ...) or is there an appropriate way to point to an external build config file, so as not to clutter the grunt conifg object?

Comment: It is in theory possible after performing a build with `r.js` to end up with a bundle that does not require any runtime configuration. This is to be determined on a case-by-case basis. An example where it would not be possible is where a developer combines all the modules, including jQuery in a single bundle and wants RequireJS to first load jQuery from a CDN and then fallback onto loading it from the bundle if the CDN is down. In this case, there has to be a runtime configuration.

Comment: If you are in a situation where you don't need a runtime configuration, then you could put everything in the build config, and not have a runtime config. I do not know of a way to point to an external *build* config. There may exist a tool that would allow this but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Cool, yeah no conditional cdn loading as of now.  Basically just need to line up modules in order within the build so I guess I'll keep it simple and just work within the grunt task config for now.  Thanks for the info!